# Flattening frameless wall mirror

Tags: mirror

So, I purchased a frameless mirror to mount on my bedroom wall and it was sitting on the floor for a few days before I had a chance to mount it.  When I mounted it today, I found that it was slightly bent and therefore will not sit flush against the wall.

Had no issues mounting it, just bugs me that it's not sitting flat.  Anyone know how I can correct it and flatten the mirror?

Comment: please update your question with a description of how you mounted it and the construction of your wall.

Comment: Also, is the mirror glass? Could the wall be out of plane?

Comment: If it's a glass mirror, it'd be odd that that it's not flat...are you SURE it's not your wall that's not flat (walls very often are not flat). Glass has a very very slight ability to bend before shattering...but it's not much.

Comment: Good point, perhaps the wall isn't flat.  Mounted it as instructed in http://video.about.com/apartments/Mount-a-Frameless-Wall-Mirror.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd agree with DA01 here. It's far more likely that your wall isn't perfectly flat rather than the mirror being distorted.

The simple way to test this is to get a spirit level - or anything with an edge you know is true - and lay it across the mirror. If it doesn't lie flush then the mirror is warped. You can do the same with the wall.